# How and How fast can we infer a logical formula that expresses a given graph in C$^2$( logic with 2 vars and counting quantifiers)?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, first-order-logic

In the following paper the author's claim that almost all graphs can be expressed in first order logic with counting quantifiers and two variables.

I would like to know, is there any algorithm that infers a C$^2$ representation of a graph ?

If there is then what is its time complexity ?

[https://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/pub/canon.pdf](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Eimmerman/pub/canon.pdf)

Comment: I do not know the answer but maybe you can find it in the Otto's book on two-variable logic: https://doi.org/10.1017/9781316716878. Or maybe it's even here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnl/1235416501 or here: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/523269

Comment: Doesn't vertex refinement, together with the proof that it's equivalent to C_2, do it? See section 1.8 of the paper you linked.